# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _node_module_register

Tags: node.js, npm

I have tried reinstalling and rebuilding npm, but the problem still persists.

Initially, the problem is with the module `mongodb`: I don't have that package, so I installed `mongodb` using this command `npm install mongodb`.

It shows me the following error: 
`dyld: Symbol not found: _node_module_register`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try deleting your node_modules folder and running npm install again.

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

That should fix it.

Comment: same goes for modules installed globally but in ~/.npm/ directory

Comment: this did not work for me, but sudo npm install worked.

Answer (score 22):

Basically this error means - *some binary packages was built under different node.js versions and not compatible to each other*.

1. Via [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) make sure you are using proper version of node.js, run `node -v`;
2. After installing and switching to proper node.js version via `nvm` run `npm update`;
3. After all packages are updated (*or downgraded*) to compatible versions, run `npm rebuild`;
4. Note: `npm rebuild` might throw errors - just run `npm rebuild` again and again until it runs successfully.

**Note:** some commands may ask for root (sudo) permissions, - it depends from how you have installed packages, npm and node itself previously. `nvm` - never needs to be run as root (sudo).

Answer (score 2):

If you just updated node and are running scripts via WebStorm, make sure you edit your Run/Debug Configurations and update the path to the Node Interpreter.  I was using the node in

```
/usr/local/bin/node
```

, but after installing Node 4 using nvm, I need to use

```
/path/to/.nvm/v4.2.2/bin/node
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
sudo npm install
```

Comment: should not run with sudo

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your **nvm is pointing** to the correct nodejs version. For me I used different (higher) while installing the npm modules. So just ran `**nvm use** v14.7.0`