# Updating mongoose to 4.2.5 breaks application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, kerberos

After updating mongoose to the latest version, when I start up my server I get the following not-very-helpful error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _node_module_register
Referenced from: /Users/michaelrusso/Development/sp-app-website/services/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos.node
Expected in: dynamic lookup

dyld: Symbol not found: _node_module_register
Referenced from: /Users/michaelrusso/Development/sp-app-website/services/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos/build/Release/kerberos.node
 Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

EDIT: this question is specific to mongoose 4.2.5

Comment: This is specific to mongoose 4.2.5. Regardless, solution posted for other question didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting your node_modules folder and running npm install again.

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

That should fix it.

Basically this error means that some binary packages were built under different node.js versions and are not compatible with each other.

Source: [dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _node_module_register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130692/dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-symbol-not-found-node-module-register)

Comment: I tried that, I also tried adding kerberos as a dependency. Neither worked.

Comment: Did you tried to delete and reinstall you globally installed node modules as well? Maybe it's worth a try. In `~/.npm/` directory

Comment: Also, did you try the steps 2 and 3 in the link? `npm update` and then `npm rebuild`? If reinstalling globally doesn't help then I advise you to try that.

Comment: My apologies, you were right.

Comment: @MusicalShore Could you mark the question as answered then? Thanks.